# Draw the graph and find the local extrema of the function $f(x)=x^3/3-2x^2+3x+1$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Draw the graph and find the local extrema of the function $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}-2x^2+3x+1$.

We have that, $f’(x)=x^2-4x+3=(x-3)(x-1)$

Hence $3$ and $1$ are critical points of $f$.

If $x\in (-\infty,1)$, then $f’(x)>0$

If $x\in (1,3)$, then $f’(x)<0$

If $x\in (3,\infty)$, then $f’(x)>0$

Therefore,

$f(1)$ is a local maximum because $f’(x)$ changes sings from + to -.

$f(3)$ is a local minimum because $f’(x)$ changes sings from - to +.

Is that true? And how can I draw the graph of $f$, please?

Comment: You want your second to last line to read $f(3)$ is a local minimum... right?

Comment: @coreyman317 Yes, you are right, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are true.

Also, $f''(x)=2x-4$, that is the curve is concave in $(-\infty, 2)$ and convex in $(2,\infty)$.

Guide:

- Plot the point $(1, f(1))$ and $(3, f(2))$.
- Draw a concave shape that passes through $(0,1)$, $(1,f(1))$ and $(2,f(2))$.
- Draw a convex shape that passes through $(2,f(2))$ and $(3,f(3))$

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is true, you can also check by finding $f''$, we say that $x$ is a maximum if $f''(x) < 0 $ and vice versa.

When drawing the graph, plot the roots of $f$, and also mark on the turning points. Join together the curve through the turning points and the roots, and also think of the behaviour of $f$ as $x \to \pm \infty$

Answer (score 2):

The guide above is clear enough

[image: The rough plot should be like this]